# Getting a control name/Displaying tooltip text

Tags: c#, gui, visual-studio, windows-forms, user-interface

I am developing a character creator using Windows Forms (because apparently I can't create menus in Unity), and I want to display some tips and descriptions in a `RichTextBox` located by the options when the user's mouse hover by its `GroupBoxes`.

Since I am fairly new to programming I don't know if getting all the controls' names one by one is the optimal, so I want to grab the controls' names inside of the `tabControl` control that I am using to organize everything.

```
private void TabControl1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                string name = c.Name;
                TooltipText(name);
            }
        }
```

And I also have a method where I will write the text that will be displayed in the `RichTextBox`

```
private string TooltipText(string name)
        {
            if(name == "Name:")
            {
                return "blabla";
            }
            else
            {
                return "none";
            }
        }
```

I've tried a generic method to show a message box if the control was detected and, as I suspected, nothing showed up:

```
private void TooltipText(string name)
        {
            if(name == "LBL_Name")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hey");
                return;
            }
        }
```

How can I properly detect the `GroupBoxes` or other types of controls inside of the `TabControl` control and also display the text in the box beside it?

Comment: What leads you to believe "apparently I can't create menus in Unity"?

Comment: @DMGregory because, at least for now, I don't have enough experience in creating menus and creating a text based, menu oriented game in Unity has been quite chealenging for me. I can't find any good or focused resources that can help me. On the other hand, a could find a lot of information on how to use windows forms, so I am trying this for now.